# How to remove/delete the ExtensionList from an Excel workbook via OpenXML?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, excel, openxml

I have 100+ workbooks that have been damaged - when they are attempted to be opened, Excel will throw an error message that says 'x' is an undeclared prefix. These files can't be loaded in an xml viewer (including the OpenXML one). Now if I change the extension of the Excel workbook to .zip, unzip all the parts, edit the following line (which is the last element in the xml document) in the workbook.xml file

```
<extLst><x:ext uri="{140A7094-0E35-4892-8432-C4D2E57EDEB5}" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"><x15:workbookPr chartTrackingRefBase="1"/></x:ext></extLst>
```

by either deleting the entire element  or by removing the `x:` in the `<ext>` tags then the workbook will function properly after I package it back up.

I've also tried the following VB.Net code:

```
 Private Sub RemoveExceptionsFromWorkbook(ByVal workbookPath As String)
        Using excelDoc As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(workbookPath, True)
            If excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants(Of WorkbookExtensionList)().Any() Then
                excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.RemoveAllChildren(Of WorkbookExtensionList)()
                excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save()
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

But I get the 'x' is an undeclared prefix error each time. Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to Vincent Tan for concept. You were right - the xml file could not be opened so I had to modify it as a text file first. First I ran this on it:

```vb
Private Sub RemovePrefix()
     'Change the extension of the workbook.xml file to txt
     IO.File.Move(WorkbookXmlFilePath, WorkbookXmlTxtFileName)  

     Dim arrText() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(WorkbookXmlTxtFileName)
     Dim arrNewText(arrText.Length - 1) As String

     For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(arrText)
          If arrText(i).Contains("x:") Then
               arrNewText(i) = Strings.Replace(arrText(i), "x:", "")
          Else
               arrNewText(i) = arrText(i)
          End If
     Next

     IO.File.WriteAllLines(WorkbookXmlTxtFileName, arrNewText)

     'Change the extension back to xml
     IO.File.Move(WorkbookXmlTxtFileName, WorkbookXmlFilePath)
End Sub
```

After that, the xml file was not corrupted anymore, but trying to open the Excel workbook still gave me a message that the data was corrupted. So the procedure from my question then worked to completely remove the `<extLst>` node from the workbook.xml document and fix the workbook.

```vb
Private Sub RemoveExceptionList(ByVal workbookPath as String)
     Using excelDoc As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(workbookPath, True)
          If excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants(Of WorkbookExtensionList)().Any() Then
               excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.RemoveAllChildren(Of WorkbookExtensionList)()
               excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save()
          End If
     End Using
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can't do it with Excel or with Open XML SDK then, because the file itself is corrupted. This means you have to modify it like a normal ZIP file. I used DotNetZip for convenience but you can use whichever ZIP library you're comfortable with. Try this:

```
using (ZipFile zf = ZipFile.Read("damagedcopy.xlsx"))
{
    ZipEntry ze = zf["xl/workbook.xml"];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ze.Extract(ms);
        // this is important, otherwise the StreamReader starts from the end.
        ms.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        string streamdata = sr.ReadToEnd();
        // I only updated the relevant portion of the XML
        streamdata = streamdata.Replace("<x:ext", "<ext");
        streamdata = streamdata.Replace("</x:ext>", "</ext>");
        sr.Close();
        zf.UpdateEntry("xl/workbook.xml", streamdata);
        zf.Save();
    }
}
```

Iterate over all 100+ Excel files (I feel your pain...) as needed.